# clients (imac's) not able to contact 587 submission port

Tags: postfix

I'm having this weird problem with my imacs not being able to contact postfix. My macbook and iphone work fine, and they are on the same network. Iphone had similar problems for a while, but magically seems to have been solved (i switched to port 465 and back to 578 that did the trick).

This is what i see in the server log when i attempt to setup a mail server account with them:

```
Aug 10 20:56:29 www postfix/smtpd[13919]: read from 5618FB3E6F90 [5618FB3F6290] (11 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
```

Anyone would say it is a local client problem. But I'm not sure what else to do besides removing the Mail.app completely or the plist files. Did anyone ever have this problem before?